# Pandas - .loc / lambda / time series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-loc

I did a web scraping which returns a table of port congestion. So each row represents a ship and its days of arrival, berthing and departure.

[Link for data source](https://lineup.prumologistica.com.br/lineup/pesquisa.aspx?WCI=relEmitirLineUp)

I'd like my code only to retrieve data of the interval from yesterday up to the 7 previous days, i.e, from the previous week until yesterday.

I tried below script to retrieve data from yesterday, which is working fine.
I am using the dates of tabela['departure'] as reference:

```
today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
today = datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')

yesterday = pd.to_datetime(today - pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00'))

df0 = tabela.loc[lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['departure'].dt.date) == yesterday, :]
```

How could I retrieve the whole interval of the previous week?

I've tried the following but it does not return the data frame:

```
time = ['1 days 00:00:00', '2 days 00:00:00', '3 days 00:00:00', '4 days 00:00:00', '5 days 00:00:00', '6 days 00:00:00', '7 days 00:00:00']

week = pd.to_datetime([today - pd.Timedelta(i) for i in time])

tabela.loc[lambda x: [ x for x in list(pd.to_datetime(x['departure'].dt.date)) if x in week],:]
```

Comment: Please post of sample of your actual data, and an example of what the correct output would look like.

Comment: Actually I was looking for answer on how to use more conditionals using .loc. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.loc`, combine multiple conditions using `&`.

`Syntax: df.loc[condition1 & condition2]`

**for your case, you can try like this.**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

today = datetime.today()
yest = today - pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
lastweek = yest - pd.Timedelta('7 days 00:00:00')

tabela.loc[(tabela['departure']<=yest) & (tabela['departure']>=lastweek)]
```

hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the solution I was looking for

Comment: Just for the records, I've just come up with a "new" and simpler solution:

`tabela.query("(departure < @today) & (departure >= last_week)")`